# Application Commands is not supported in WPF

Tags: wpf, commandbinding

using WPF (beginner) :-)

i keep getting the error 
"ApplicationCommans is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project"

i just begin my project ..

Solution Platform : AnyCPU

```
<Window x:Class="Wpf_CreatingARichTextEditor.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Wpf_CreatingARichTextEditor"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="400">

  <Window.CommandBindings> 

    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommans.Open"
                    Executed="CommandBinding_Executed" />

  </Window.CommandBindings>

    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

thanks

Comment: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/commands/using-commands/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not ApplicationCommans..it's ApplicationCommands.Open. Just change the name of the command it should fix the issue.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I got this issue when copying from MSDN and pasting into the XAML.  There was an invisible zero-width joiner character between Application and Commands that I had to delete (presumably to help with word-wrapping)

Comment: Upvoted because it explains how someone might have mispelled ApplicationCommands to ApplicationCommans